# Angular crud dinamico

Tags: angularjs-2.0, angular2-template

Estoy creando un crud dinamico , que me permite pasar como parámetros los elementos que se van a mostrar en una tabla para cualquier tipo de crud (usuarios, categorías, permisos, etc) Entonces, dependiendo del tipo de crud, Las opciones correspondientes (los modelos para el formulario, así como el tipo y el nombre)

```
import { Component,Input,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CrudFactoryService } from '../../services';

interface Hero {
    name?:String;
    userName?:String,
    email?:String,
    age?:String,
    password?:String

}


@Component({
    selector:'crud',
    templateUrl:'crud.component.html',
})

export class CrudComponent implements OnInit{
    @Input() items;
    @Input() type:string;
    model:Hero={};
    options:any;

    constructor(private cfs:CrudFactoryService){
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        console.log("type=="+this.type);
        this.options=this.cfs.getOptions(this.type);
     }

     create(model2){
         console.log("model2==",model2)
                 console.log("model1==",this.model)
         console.log("Create User pressed")
     }
     sendToUpdate(user){

     }
}
```

Las opciones que le traigo a través de una api

```
export const CRUDUSER=[
    {nameForm:"id"},
    {nameForm:"Nombres",nameModel:{name:"model.name",name2:"name",type:"text"}},
        {nameForm:"Nick",nameModel:{name:"model.userName",name2:"userName",type:"text"}},

    {nameForm:"Correo",nameModel:{name:"model.email",name2:"email",type:"email"}},

    {nameForm:"Edad",nameModel:{name:"model.age",name2:"age",type:"number"}},
    {nameForm:"Fecha Registro"},
    {nameModel:{name:"model.password",name2:"password",type:"password"}}

    ]
```

Cuando ejecuto la aplicación todo funciona bien excepto por una cosa

Que mi ngModel, no se actualiza cuando introdujo un nuevo valor en la entrada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando cambio un valor, el valor del enlace se cambia al valor introducido, user.name === fdfdf, lo sé por enlace de datos, usando sólo [] en el modelo yano obtengo este error, lo que parece extraño No vi esta pregunta

Cuando envío submit invocation al método create (), pero me lanza que el usuario anterior está vacío

Aquí está mi html donde enlazar los datos (opciones) traídos de la api

```
......
......
......
        <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let op of options |async,let i=index">
        <ng-container *ngIf="op.nameModel">
          <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="op.nameModel.name"  class="form-control" id="{{op.nameForm}}" placeholder="{{op.nameForm}}"
          name="{{op.nameModel.name2}}">
        </ng-container>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" (click)="create(model)" >Submit</button>
      </form>
.....
....
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es, ¿cómo resolver este problema?

Answer (score 0):

El `ngModel` de cada `input` está haciendo el dual binding con la propiedad `op.nameModel.name` tal cual especificaste, si la idea es usar el valor que contiene `op.nameModel.name` (por ejemplo `model.name`) entonces podrías probar de cambiar la expresión de `ngModel` para que apunte a una propiedad de `model`:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="model[op.nameModel.name2]"  class="form-control" id="{{op.nameForm}}" placeholder="{{op.nameForm}}"
      name="{{op.nameModel.name2}}">
```

Aunque `model` y `model2` evidentemente refieren al mismo objeto.